# How to hide GtkStackSwitcher?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am trying to programmatically toggle between the `GtkStack` within a `GtkStackSwitcher`. In Glade, I unchecked the `visible` flag, but the `GtkStackSwitcher` is always visible, I even tried to hide the switcher itself using `gtk_widget_hide(mySwitcher);` at the beginning of my initialization code.

Is there a way to hide the switcher? I am not able to find any examples whether is from Python or C++ (what I am working on) to draw ideas from. Or is this not possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use `gtk_widget_destroy` to destroy the switcher itself at run time... since the control flow is one-sided (switcher controlling the stack), if you are 100% sure that you don't need it afterwards, you could destroy it.

For me, I was using Glade to design various dynamic screens with Switcher + Stack and I only need to programmatically toggle my stack/page once when the application initialized.  little ugly and hacky but it looks like there is no way to hide a Switcher widget in GTK3.